# Free Angular 2 scheduler

Tags: angular, components, scheduler

I want to include a scheduler into my angular 2 app. I need something like those, to plan different employees in a day view:
here are 2 links to paid components which could fit my purpose:
https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.6.2/demos/external-dragging.html
https://www.bryntum.com/playpen/angular2/
Since I can't afford any pricy pro licences right now, I'm looking for something open source and also more lightweight. I want to drag and drop "appointments" in a grid like day-view.
 Does somebody now if it is possible to build such a view with the PrimeNG schedule (which is full calendar)?

Any hints for other components I could use?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can do that take a look at this live demo of PrimeNG.

http://primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule

Comment: isnt this the fullcalender version without the "premium add-on" scheduler?I don't think you can use the ressourse planing feature, can you?

Comment: Correct. It does not include the premium add-on. I am also looking for something similar

Comment: has anyone found it ?

Comment: I'm still looking for a ressourse planning  solution, any help ?

Comment: http://primefaces.org/primeng/#/fullcalendar this is their most updated version @Abhishek

Comment: thanks for the updated link, but this scheduler not fulfilling even the basic requirements.